# Problem Exporting from Dia to Latex PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts, export

Hello I am having problem with exporting a flow chart made with [Dia](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Dia?action=show&redirect=Dia) to PGF macros. In short this is the flow made with Dia

[image]

I exported to L<sup>a</sup>T<sub>e</sub>X PGF with the following code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\ifx\du\undefined
  \newlength{\du}
\fi
\setlength{\du}{15\unitlength}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgftransformxscale{1.000000}
\pgftransformyscale{-1.000000}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-15.400000\du,-4.000000\du)--(-15.400000\du,1.100000\du)--(-5.750000\du,1.100000\du)--(-5.750000\du,-4.000000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-15.400000\du,-4.000000\du)--(-15.400000\du,1.100000\du)--(-5.750000\du,1.100000\du)--(-5.750000\du,-4.000000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-10.575000\du,-2.294233\du){Ostruzione Renale};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-10.575000\du,-1.233078\du){Acuta};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-10.575000\du,-0.171922\du){};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-10.590259\du,1.150070\du)--(-10.647776\du,10.950406\du);
}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-16.000000\du,11.000000\du)--(-16.000000\du,16.344622\du)--(-5.327500\du,16.344622\du)--(-5.327500\du,11.000000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-16.000000\du,11.000000\du)--(-16.000000\du,16.344622\du)--(-5.327500\du,16.344622\du)--(-5.327500\du,11.000000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-10.663750\du,12.297500\du){Aumento della Pressione};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-10.663750\du,13.358656\du){Endoluminale e };
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-10.663750\du,14.419811\du){della Pelvi Renale};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-10.663750\du,15.480967\du){};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (-1.700000\du,5.000000\du){};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (5.800000\du,21.000000\du)--(-24.600000\du,20.972351\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-24.613016\du,21.068075\du)--(-24.580000\du,23.813934\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-8.867868\du,21.043223\du)--(-8.862868\du,24.281066\du);
}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-29.300000\du,23.325356\du)--(-29.300000\du,28.669978\du)--(-19.830000\du,28.669978\du)--(-19.830000\du,23.325356\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-29.300000\du,23.325356\du)--(-29.300000\du,28.669978\du)--(-19.830000\du,28.669978\du)--(-19.830000\du,23.325356\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-24.565000\du,24.622856\du){Iperperistalsi};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-24.565000\du,25.684012\du){e Spasmo degli};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-24.565000\du,26.745167\du){Ureteri};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-24.565000\du,27.806323\du){};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-13.687868\du,24.281066\du)--(-13.687868\du,27.901066\du)--(-4.037868\du,27.901066\du)--(-4.037868\du,24.281066\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-13.687868\du,24.281066\du)--(-13.687868\du,27.901066\du)--(-4.037868\du,27.901066\du)--(-4.037868\du,24.281066\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-8.862868\du,25.777411\du){Nocicettori};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-8.862868\du,26.838566\du){};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (1.000000\du,23.000000\du)--(1.000000\du,29.405778\du)--(10.470000\du,29.405778\du)--(10.470000\du,23.000000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (1.000000\du,23.000000\du)--(1.000000\du,29.405778\du)--(10.470000\du,29.405778\du)--(10.470000\du,23.000000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.735000\du,24.297500\du){};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.735000\du,25.358656\du){Distensione della };
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.735000\du,26.419811\du){Capsula Renale};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.735000\du,27.480967\du){};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.735000\du,28.542122\du){};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsstart{stealth}
\pgfsetarrowsend{stealth}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (11.173254\du,26.011474\du)--(14.063813\du,26.022332\du);
}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (14.063813\du,23.350021\du)--(14.063813\du,28.694643\du)--(23.751176\du,28.694643\du)--(23.751176\du,23.350021\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (14.063813\du,23.350021\du)--(14.063813\du,28.694643\du)--(23.751176\du,28.694643\du)--(23.751176\du,23.350021\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (18.907495\du,24.647521\du){};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (18.907495\du,25.708676\du){Dolore};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (18.907495\du,26.769832\du){};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (18.907495\du,27.830987\du){};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-29.730828\du,31.407201\du)--(-29.730828\du,35.792268\du)--(-19.460828\du,35.792268\du)--(-19.460828\du,31.407201\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-29.730828\du,31.407201\du)--(-29.730828\du,35.792268\du)--(-19.460828\du,35.792268\du)--(-19.460828\du,31.407201\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-24.595828\du,32.755501\du){Prolungata Contrazione};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-24.595828\du,33.816657\du){Isotonica};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-24.595828\du,34.877812\du){};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-24.580512\du,28.719603\du)--(-24.595828\du,31.407201\du);
}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-13.633057\du,30.503159\du)--(-13.633057\du,35.847781\du)--(-4.163057\du,35.847781\du)--(-4.163057\du,30.503159\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-13.633057\du,30.503159\du)--(-13.633057\du,35.847781\du)--(-4.163057\du,35.847781\du)--(-4.163057\du,30.503159\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-8.898057\du,31.800659\du){Impulsi Afferenti};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-8.898057\du,32.861815\du){Midollo Spinale };
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-8.898057\du,33.922970\du){T11-L1};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-8.898057\du,34.984126\du){};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-8.862868\du,27.901066\du)--(-8.898057\du,30.503159\du);
}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (0.079409\du,30.608978\du)--(0.079409\du,37.014755\du)--(11.469409\du,37.014755\du)--(11.469409\du,30.608978\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (0.079409\du,30.608978\du)--(0.079409\du,37.014755\du)--(11.469409\du,37.014755\du)--(11.469409\du,30.608978\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.774409\du,31.906478\du){Immediato aumento 1.5 hr};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.774409\du,32.967633\du){del flusso renale -->};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.774409\du,34.028789\du){ diuresi --> aumento};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.774409\du,35.089944\du){pressione pelvi renale};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.774409\du,36.151100\du){};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (5.751849\du,29.456117\du)--(5.757559\du,30.558638\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsstart{stealth}
\pgfsetarrowsend{stealth}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (11.469409\du,33.811866\du)--(14.474438\du,33.712176\du);
}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (14.474438\du,31.570443\du)--(14.474438\du,35.853909\du)--(24.124438\du,35.853909\du)--(24.124438\du,31.570443\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (14.474438\du,31.570443\du)--(14.474438\du,35.853909\du)--(24.124438\du,35.853909\du)--(24.124438\du,31.570443\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (19.299438\du,32.867943\du){Mediato da };
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (19.299438\du,33.929098\du){Prostglandine};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (19.299438\du,34.990254\du){};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-30.005472\du,38.478269\du)--(-30.005472\du,42.863335\du)--(-19.115472\du,42.863335\du)--(-19.115472\du,38.478269\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-30.005472\du,38.478269\du)--(-30.005472\du,42.863335\du)--(-19.115472\du,42.863335\du)--(-19.115472\du,38.478269\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-24.560472\du,39.826569\du){Cascata Infiammatoria ed};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-24.560472\du,40.887724\du){ischemia muscolare};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-24.560472\du,41.948880\du){};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-24.584613\du,35.842675\du)--(-24.571687\du,38.427862\du);
}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-13.597702\du,38.407558\du)--(-13.597702\du,42.792625\du)--(-4.127702\du,42.792625\du)--(-4.127702\du,38.407558\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-13.597702\du,38.407558\du)--(-13.597702\du,42.792625\du)--(-4.127702\du,42.792625\du)--(-4.127702\du,38.407558\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-8.862702\du,39.755858\du){Dolore viscerale };
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-8.862702\du,40.817014\du){Nausea/Vomito};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-8.862702\du,41.878169\du){};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-8.898057\du,35.847781\du)--(-8.862702\du,38.407558\du);
}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (0.905230\du,38.521766\du)--(0.905230\du,45.988699\du)--(10.657730\du,45.988699\du)--(10.657730\du,38.521766\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (0.905230\du,38.521766\du)--(0.905230\du,45.988699\du)--(10.657730\du,45.988699\du)--(10.657730\du,38.521766\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.781480\du,39.819266\du){Nelle 4.5 hr successive};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.781480\du,40.880422\du){pressione pelvica};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.781480\du,41.941577\du){rimane alta ma};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.781480\du,43.002733\du){il flusso renale e GFR si};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.781480\du,44.063888\du){riducono};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.781480\du,45.125044\du){};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsstart{stealth}
\pgfsetarrowsend{stealth}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (11.228854\du,42.157194\du)--(13.701436\du,42.155365\du);
}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (14.340087\du,38.294285\du)--(14.340087\du,45.761218\du)--(23.990087\du,45.761218\du)--(23.990087\du,38.294285\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (14.340087\du,38.294285\du)--(14.340087\du,45.761218\du)--(23.990087\du,45.761218\du)--(23.990087\du,38.294285\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (19.165087\du,39.591785\du){Mediato da };
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (19.165087\du,40.652941\du){Angiotensina II,};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (19.165087\du,41.714096\du){Trmoboxani ,};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (19.165087\du,42.775252\du){ormone antidiuretico,};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (19.165087\du,43.836407\du){endotelina};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (19.165087\du,44.897563\du){};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-0.387270\du,48.066637\du)--(-0.387270\du,54.094237\du)--(11.950230\du,54.094237\du)--(11.950230\du,48.066637\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-0.387270\du,48.066637\du)--(-0.387270\du,54.094237\du)--(11.950230\du,54.094237\du)--(11.950230\du,48.066637\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.781480\du,49.705626\du){Dopo 5hr si ha una riduzione };
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.781480\du,50.766781\du){del flusso ematico, pressione};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.781480\du,51.827937\du){ureterale, e GFR};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (5.781480\du,52.889092\du){};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (5.781480\du,45.988699\du)--(5.781480\du,48.066637\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (5.774409\du,37.014755\du)--(5.781480\du,38.521766\du);
}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 1.000000, 0.988235}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-29.500533\du,45.379631\du)--(-29.500533\du,49.133866\du)--(-19.695533\du,49.133866\du)--(-19.695533\du,45.379631\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-29.500533\du,45.379631\du)--(-29.500533\du,49.133866\du)--(-19.695533\du,49.133866\du)--(-19.695533\du,45.379631\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-24.598033\du,47.473671\du){Colica Renale};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-24.560472\du,42.863335\du)--(-24.581559\du,45.329803\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (5.850000\du,20.950000\du)--(5.806215\du,22.949971\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-10.658644\du,16.393360\du)--(-10.650000\du,21.000000\du);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the result of the processed file. Why is not exporting the whole diagram ?

Comment: I compiled your code (after writing \begin{document}) and the result is the whole diagram.

Comment: Yes I was able too to compile the document , but I cannot get the whole [diagram](https://i.imgur.com/J6INgJR.png)

Comment: It is not possible you got the complete diagram . Can you post a screenshot of your pdf file ?

Comment: I posted the screenshot in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled your code (after writing `\begin{document}`, because there isn't it in your code) and the result is the whole diagram:

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks ,my mistake  I put the command after `setlenght`